# Incremental head -n in bash for loop

Tags: bash

How can I do a incremental for loop, for the -n in the head command (head -n)?

Does this work?

```
for (( i = 1 ; i <= $NUMBER ; i++ ))
head -$(NUMBER) filename.txt
NUMBER=$((NUMBER+1))
done
```

The code is suppose to display different texts off from filename.txt using the -n

Comment: Are you trying to get "chunks" of the file? Each loop gets you the next X lines? Or are you trying to get one line, then two lines, then three lines starting from the first line of the file each time? Show input and output?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get chunks of the file. Each loop will get me the text at that specific line, and when the loop runs again it will show me the text at the next line.

Comment: What's the actual goal here? This feels a bit [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Are you really trying to read from the file line-by-line or N-lines-by-N-lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for (( i = 1 ; i < `wc -l filename.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '` ; i++ )); do
  head -$i filename.txt | tail -1; 
done
```

The `wc -l filename.txt` gets the number of lines in `filename.txt`. `cut -f 1 -f ' '` takes the first field from the `wc` which is the number of lines. This is used as the upper bound for the loop.

`head -$i` takes the first `$i` lines and `tail -1` takes the last line of that. This gives you one line blocks.

Comment: Works like a charm. Is it possible to append the output of the head command to a variable?

Comment: That would be a separate question but you can do an append to a variable $X using `X=$X'whateverYouWantToAppend`.
It is starting to seem like this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you might be better off asking your problem X instead of asking about Y.